# Is possible to determine location on 3g/4g mifi-hotspot devices

Tags: privacy, geolocation

I ask for...
I use Huawi 4g router for internet connection. It is works outdoor and i use nanostation as datalink. can anyone determine my geolocation. if it possible how much meter accuarcy.

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely possible.  You are using a cellular network, which means, at the very least, the operator of the cellular tower knows where you are, within roughly a 22-45 mile radius.  If you are within the range of two or more towers, triangulation can be used to pinpoint your location to a fairly precise degree.  This is based the signal strength and the number of towers in range.  As to how precise, I do not know.  That would be better answered by someone in the wireless telecom industry.  I do know that more precise equipment is available to track radio signals, as that is not the primary function of cellular towers.  If you are broadcasting radio signals, you can always be found.

Additionally, if the hotspot or something connected to it has a GPS in it, it is entirely possible that your exact location is being revealed to within 4 meters.